# Dominated Convergence Theorem in Stochastic Calculus (Infinite Dimensional Spaces)

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Is there an established Dominated Convergence Theorem version for the stochastic setting? Particularly in infinite dimensional spaces. I have a hard time finding such books. Cite some resources please. Thanks! :)

Comment: Are you asking if there is a dominated convergence theorem for stochastic integrals?

Comment: @K.Power yes sir..